# Подставить вместо wp-admin , 404 ошибку

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, apache

Как сделать, чтобы  при заходе  по адресу site/wp-admin  отображалась ошибка  404?
Пробовал сделать так:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.28\.5$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
</IfModule>
```

Нужно, чтобы отдавал 404 ошибку, и чтобы отображалась 404 ошибка сгенерированная wordpress’ом. (если использовать пример, который я написал выше, то он игнорирует все вставки “get_header, get_sidebar” и так далее).
Нельзя, чтобы в адресной строке менялся адрес (например: site/404.php). Должно быть, как при стандартной отработке wordpress’a.

Answer (score 3):

Вот этот способ пробовали? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-the-admin-url-or-wp-admin-to-secure-login

1 Добавить константу в wp-confing.php

```
define('WP_ADMIN_DIR', 'secret-folder');
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . WP_ADMIN_DIR);
```

2 Добавить фильтр в functions.php

```
add_filter('site_url',  'wpadmin_filter', 10, 3);
function wpadmin_filter($url, $path, $orig_scheme) {
    $old = array("/(wp-admin)/");
    $admin_dir = WP_ADMIN_DIR;
    $new  = array($admin_dir);
    return preg_replace($old, $new, $url, 1);
}
```

3 Добавить строку в .htaccess файл

`RewriteRule ^secret-folder/(.*) wp-admin/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Будет проще установить плагин, там по моему только одну галочку нужно будет поставить в настройках. Название - Lockdown WP. 
Галочку поставьте на: Yes, please hide WP Admin from the user when they aren't logg. Ниже можете указать любую другую ссылку на админку вордпресса.

Answer (score 0):

Можно зацепиться за actions которые отвечают за вывод админки и форм авторизации в файле wp-login.php

```
    add_action('admin_init', 'admin_404');
    add_action('login_init', 'admin_404');
//Ограничиваем доступ к админке WP
function admin_404()
{
    global $wp_query;
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options') || !is_user_logged_in()) {
        if (!defined('DOING_AJAX') || !DOING_AJAX) {
            $wp_query->set_404();
            status_header(404);
            $template = get_404_template();
            if ($template = apply_filters('template_include', $template)) {
                include($template);
            }
            wp_die();
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо открыть папку wp-admin и там создать новый файл .htaccess
В этот файл просто вставить код:
Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from *.*.*.* (вместо *.*.*.* указать свой IP

Если кто-либо захочет зайти на сайт/wp-admin/ увидит ошибку 403.